# UITableViewCell is hidden.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in my controller. The cells for the `UITableView` have xib.
For some reason, when the table is loaded, the views of the cells are hidden.

I can select the cell, I see that the cell is not nil, and the views are not nil as well, still the cell is hidden.

Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CategoryCell";
    CategoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray* topObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        for (id obj in topObjects){
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[CategoryCell class]]){
                cell = (CategoryCell*)obj;
            }
        }
    }

    id object;
    if (indexPath.row < items.count)
        object = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[MenuCategory class]]) {
        // Configure the cell   
        MenuCategory *cellInfo = (MenuCategory *)object;
        [cell setCategory:cellInfo];
        }
    else if([object isKindOfClass:[MenuSubCategory class]]){
        // Configure the cell   
        MenuSubCategory *cellInfo = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell setSubCategory:cellInfo];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You will need to retain this cell = (CategoryCell*)[obj retain];, it may not solve this issue, but regardless it should be retained

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I've added the retain. But that didn't help.

Comment: problem is with contents in cell as cell are referenced correctly try to check [cell setSubCategory:cellInfo];
 or   [cell setSubCategory:cellInfo];
 workin or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O so sorry wasting your time.

The solution is nothing to do with code.

The table was narrower then the cells. So the text (that was written on the left side of the cell) was outside of the table bounds. And that is why it was missing from the screen.

Comment: Oddly enough, I'm creating a table view programmatically, and have the delegate specified, and am creating custom subclasses of UITableViewCell, and nowhere is there a cell.hidden = YES; however all my cells are hidden by default.

Too bad there was no surprise solution in this topic.

Comment: gotta clarify my solution that I've resolved. The tableview was part of a UITableViewController custom subclass I was instantiating, and after instantiating it, it was being released by ARC, despite its tableview property being contained within a view hierarchy.  Anyway, adding the subclassed UITableViewController object as a strong property, the cells are no longer hidden. :)

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
NSArray* topObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        for (id obj in topObjects){
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[CategoryCell class]]){
                cell = (CategoryCell*)obj;
            }
        }
```

Replace this with

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
```

and declare an IBOutlet in your class that becomes the owner of the xib. This outlet can point to your cell. You then have to connect the `Files Owner` (has to be of the class the above code is in) within the Cell XIB to your cell. You can then reference your cell (after having declared a property for example) by

```
self.myCellOutlet;
```

and don't have to enumerate on all the objects within the xib.

Are you sure that this

```
[cell setSubCategory:cellInfo];
```

works?

If you really think your cell is just hidden, did you try to send it a

```
[cell setHidden:NO];
```

just in order to see if that's the case and if the error isn't different from the visibility state?

Comment: Hi pbx,
I've checked, the view is not hidden. It is just no shown. 
The line of code, you have asked about, is working for sure.
Regarding your proposal, thank you very much for the effort, but I would prefer the standard approach.

Comment: No problem. Just thought it would make your code more readable ;-)